# JSONParser missing from JDK

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have JDK 11 installed on my machine. I had thought that a JSON parser is now included standard with the JDK. However when I try to resolve the javax.json.* package Eclipse tells me that it is now found.
Why?

Tried searching for an answer and am coming up dry. Would appreciate an answer or a link to one.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there is a difference between Java EE and Java SE. JSON parsing is needed with enterprise applications nowadays. Oracle has a dependency you can download:

https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/

If you are using maven, you can just include this in your POM:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**BUT**, this has been superseded by the Jakarta EE package (ee4j):

**(GitHub download)**
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonp

**(Maven download)**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.json/jakarta.json-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If you look at EE4J, you can see there are so many APIs you can download. Java SE would be so bloated with them by default. For a while, Oracle was just distributing these 'reference implementations' of Java EE packages as well along with various servers like Glassfish. There are so many ways to handle these protocols and formats like JSON, and on the job these may be mission-critical.

Comment: This seems like a saner route to travel. Of course if I need to download a library I could just opt for 3rd party implementation. As I don't want to get mired down in trying to deploy the Java EE, onto my Tomcat install. When you say superseded are you saying that the JDK native JSON parser will no longer be developed? And people will be "encouraged" to use the Jakarta one? At the moment I'm using the JSON parser that comes with Tomcat.

Comment: You can just download the jsonp dependency instead of the entire ee4j. From this link https://github.com/javaee/jsonp: "This project is now part of the EE4J initiative. This repository has been archived as all activities are now happening in the corresponding Eclipse repository." The Eclipse Foundation maintains these, for better or worse, which is a non-profit. If Tomcat's works that's great, but (from their site) "Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that...from Java EE to Jakarta EE...transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package ...has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*"

Comment: This may be an illegal extension of the thread but in my head it is related. :D Since I'll be using a 3rd party library anyway I saw a benchmark that showed dsl-json parser as the fastest option out there. Do you have any experience with it? Would you still use the jakarta parser?

Comment: Interesting, speed matters sometimes. There are many options when it comes to JSON or parsing in general and sometimes you have specific requirements, like handling over-sized datasets, or using a parser that doesn't crash with malformed data (have needed both of these). I asked a coworker who uses Spring and recommended Jackson and Gson, but Jackson came built in, so there's that. See comparisons in the Conclusion section here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson. I've used a bunch and can't recommend one over the other, tend to stick with simple, fast, standard APIs when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are available as a part of Java ME and EE and not in SE.

https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/json/api/index.html?com/oracle/json/stream/JsonParser.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html

Try using Java ME or EE, you'll get that.

//Happy learning..!